# Synchronize audio loop and notes in tone.js

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, tone.js

I am experimenting with library [tone.js](https://tonejs.github.io). I would like to synchronize an audio loop file (1 bar 120 bpm) with a sequence of notes generated inside tone.js using one of the default instruments.

These are the main steps I've tried:

- Loading the audio loop in a [Player](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/r13/Player)
- Synchronize the Player to the [Transport](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/r13/Transport)
- Create a [Sequence](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/r13/Sequence) of notes
- Start the sequence
- Start the Transport (1 second after page load)

This is the code:

```
const player = new Tone.Player("path/to/loop.mp3").toMaster() // 1 bar, 

120 bpm audio loop
player.autostart = true
player.loop = true
player.sync() // sync player to Transport

const notes = ["C2", "C3"]

const synth = new Tone.Synth().toMaster()
synth.oscillator.set({type: "fatsawtooth"})
synth.envelope.set({attack: 0.05, decay: 0.2, sustain: 0.1, release: 0.1})
synth.volume.value = -8

const synthPart = new Sequence(
    function(time, note) {
        synth.triggerAttackRelease(note, "8n", time)
    },
    notes,
    "8n"
)

synthPart.start()
Transport.start(1)
```

The loop and sequence start playing at the same time but the timing is a bit off (not perfectly in sync). Is the above the correct way to sync audio and notes? Or is there anything I can do to improve the timing?